# Flexslider nav buttons at bottom are not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexslider

I am using flexslider 2 (basic style). The left and right arrows are displayed correctly,  but the navigation buttons at the bottom of the images are not being displayed. I have hunted here and via Google for a solution, but I can only find answers that relate to the side navigation arrows (which are working fine), and not to the buttons underneath

In the head tag I have added `controlNav: true` but it hasn't made any difference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    controlNav: true,
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
</script>
```

and the flexslider.css has:

```
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

I tried changing `bottom: -40px;` to `bottom: -100px;` , thinking the nav buttons may be hidden under the image, but that did not make any difference either.

I have checked that the font files are in the correct place, and indeed they must be, otherwise the arrows would not be displayed, but I cannot see why the dots don't show. I am sure it will be something simple I have done wrong.

Comment: This has been marked by someone (anonymous) as unclear or not useful. What further information would you like? Regards, Tog

Comment: The downvote may have come from someone who felt that the question [violated this guideline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). I have removed the link to your site, since it seems to me that the question is fairly understandable without it. If it is necessary to view the link in order to grok the question the the question is off-topic, since the test link you posted is likely to be deleted in short order anyway.

Comment: It's worth noting that questions here are shaped and moderated for the benefit of future readers, and so we need them to be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: @halfer Yes, the URL link was a temporary measure I thought might help someone to understand my question better. It turns out I was wrong, so I see the point now, but it would have been far better and much more helpful to me and future readers to explain that at the time rather than simply vote down without a reason. perhaps now that the link is removed you could vote it back up?

Comment: I didn't downvote on this one. It would be nice if everyone explained their downvotes, but anonymity is allowed, and people often vote and run `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or remove `overflow: hidden` from `.flexslider`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it :-)